# Topologically equivalent and lipschitz equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I am looking for an example of a metric that is topologically equivalent but not lipschitz equivalent. Can you help me? I would be very happy if you can give such an example. I thought a lot but could not find it, it is difficult to produce an example. I wish you good work.

That is, $d$ and $d'$ will be topologically equivalent, but lipschitz will not meet the equivalence condition.

Lipschitz equivalent metric: Let $(X,d)$,$(X,d')$ be metric spaces.$\forall x,y\in X$ ve $\exists r,s\in \mathbb{R^+}$,

$r d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)\leq s d(x,y)$

Comment: Hint: Let $\mathbb{D}^2$ be the unit disk. Let $X = \mathbb{D}^2 -(0,0)$ and $X' = \mathbb{R}^2 - (0,0)$.

Comment: Why did you buy two different spaces? I do not understand. @ElchananSolomon

Comment: The spaces are homeomorphic (topologically equivalent), so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I am looking for two metrics. @ElchananSolomon